# Can I cash a check with my name listed as Attn:?

Tags: united-states, check

I am currently the treasurer for a student organization at my university in the United States. The organization has recently received a check made out as shown:

```
Name of University
Attn: My Name
Address of University
Address of University
```

The standard way to handle these checks is to deposit them into our university managed financial account. However, the organization usually avoids using this account when possible because it is such a hassle to use (it takes so long to make a withdrawal that usually somebody just has to pay out of pocket and wait months to get reimbursed). Instead, we keep most of our money in a cash box that we use for day to day transactions. Is it possible for me to cash this check at a regular bank so we could use the money immediately?

Comment: If it's made to the University, and not even the club... I'd ask the person who wrote the check to cut a new one and make it out to the club.

Comment: Is all of that on the Payee line? Why is the address included?